# Angular 7 App not displaying project properly in Github pages, only shows readme

Tags: angular, github

I'm trying to push a new portfolio I'm working on to GitHub pages, with a custom domain by GoDaddy. But whenever I open the page, it just shows the readme file. I have tried various people's solutions but to no result. I have tried changing the branch to gh-pages, I have tried moving index.html to the top of the project instead of in the src folder and nothing seems to be changing. I'm not sure what to do because when I move the index.html from src to the main folder it doesnt serve in the Angular CLI.

Here is the GitHub repo https://github.com/crsbcn/portfolio
The attempted domain is chrisbacani.com

Whatever I try it only displays the readme. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also -- tried using the ng build and ng --dir. gh pages is installed on the CLI globally as well.

Comment: you are looking to host your app on GitHub. then github.io is the place

Comment: Already hosted by github.io. Same readme file. When you go to crsbcn.github.io/portfolio that's the same result as when you go to the domain I bought.

Comment: like this https://www.techiediaries.com/deploy-angular-github-pages/?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that too. Step by step. Still just shows me the read me.

Comment: you have your dist folder contents as base folder right? not the repository. how come your dist folder has readme. you should have index.html in your base folder for gh pages. If index.html is not found it will default to readme

Comment: Ok, so I tried that... making SOME progress. Now the page goes to the index, and I know it's working properly publishing the project because it has my description in the tab "Chris Bacani - Full Stack Web Developer" but it comes up empty as far as content, at least it's not the readme. I made a new repo because I'm fairly sure I botched the first one. Here's the new one: https://github.com/crsbcn/portfolio-angular-d2. And the current gh page deployment is crsbcn.github.io/portfolio-angular-d2. I'm going to straighten it out first before I move it to GoDaddy. Any further help would be great!

Comment: I ran out of room on the previous comment -- but it compiles successfully in my code editor and it shows the content as I've built thus far when accessed via the localhost. It's just the pages deployment that comes up 100% blank. Only white space.

Comment: @joyBlanks I actually got it working based on a combination of your suggestion, and then using the docs folder as the source for my source in gh pages. It's just kind of slow to materialize that's why it's not showing right away. Regardless, thank you so much.